# reset and shift only one level deep (delimited continuations)?

Tags: continuations, scheme

I'm looking at the following tutorial on delimited (or composable) continuations:

http://community.schemewiki.org/?composable-continuations-tutorial

The author(s) propose the following "rewrite rule"

```
 (reset (...A... (shift K E) ...B...)) 
 ; --> 
 (let ((K (lambda (x) (reset (...A... x ...B...))))) 
   (reset E)) 

 (reset E) 
 ; --> 
 E
```

This is vastly smaller than anything else I've been able to find on delimited continuations, and doesn't rely on Haskell's Cont monad or on Scheme's call/cc and unique macro system. Therefore, it looks like I can implement this myself to play with outside of Haskell or Scheme / Racket, and that would be grand (see my Mathematica version below).  Problem is that I don't think it's right.

If I fire up Racket, do `(require racket/control)` and then

```
(reset (+ 1 (shift k (k 42)))  ~~>  43
```

as expected and as consistent with the above.  If I do

```
(reset (+ 1 (* 2 (shift k (k 42)))))  ~~>  85
```

this looks right, but doesn't match the prescription above.  That prescription, if I read it correctly, should lead to the second rewrite rule and just produce `(+ 1 (* 2 (shift k (k 42))))` because it can't "see" the `shift` at the second level, "inside" the `(* 2 (shift ...))` subexpression.

My straight transcription into Mathematica confirms this behavior,

```
reset[h_[As___, shift[k_, E_], Bs___]] :=
  Block[{K = Function[x, reset[h[As, x, Bs]]]},
   reset[E /. {k -> K}]]
reset[E_] := E
```

One level deep (like almost all the concrete examples I've found in papers! so the wiki authors are exonerated), and everything is fine:

```
reset[1 + shift[k, k[42]]] ~~>  
reset[Plus[1, shift[k, k[42]]]] ~~>
(* h -> Plus, As -> {1}, E -> k[42], Bs -> {} *)
reset[Plus[1, 42]] ~~>
43
```

But then I try this:

```
reset[1 + (2 * shift[k, k[42]])] ~~>
reset[Plus[1, Times[2, shift[k, k[42]]]]] ~~>
1 + (2 * shift[k, k[42]])
```

This fires the second, transparent rewrite rule because `shift` is too far down; the first pattern `h[As___, shift[k_, E_], Bs___]` can't see it -- it's inside `Bs`, which matches the second-level AST `Times[2, shift[...]]`.

So the final question is:

Can I just patch the rewrite rule above, perhaps like this:

```
 (reset (...A... (shift K E) ...B...)) 
 ; --> 
 (let ((K (lambda (x) (reset ( (reset ...A...) x (reset ...B...)))))) 
   (reset E)) 

 (reset E) 
 ; --> 
 E
```

or am I doomed to take the long, scenic tour through vast landscapes of Haskell and OchaCaml and call/cc and denotational semantics just so I can create a small, but correct, toy implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misreading those rewrite rules.

A call to shift will find to the *nearest enclosing* call to reset, regardless of how deeply nested it is. Other examples in the tutorial you linked to should confirm that.

The [Racket Reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html?q=shift&=&=#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontrol..rkt%29._reset%29%29) has a slightly different set of rewrite rules for reset/shift, that might make things a little clearer.

```
(reset val) => val

(reset E[(shift k expr)]) =>
  (reset ((lambda (k) expr)
          (lambda (v) (reset E[v]))))
```

Using your example:

```
(reset (+ 1 (* 2 (shift k (k 42)))))
=>
(reset ((lambda (k) (k 42))
          (lambda (v) (reset (+ 1 (* 2 v))))))
=>
(reset (reset (+ 1 (* 2 42))))
=> 85
```

I don't speak Mathematica, but it might be possible to transcribe the rewrite rules from the Racket Reference to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found an implementation in Clojure that's in terms of fairly elementary functions and macros (rewriters) that I can translate into other languages like Mathematica or C++ or even python with [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy).  I think this will be easier for me to deal with than the implementations in Haskell (with its deep monad libraries, which I don't want to translate into other languages [too much work]) or Scheme (with its built-in `call/cc`, which I can't translate into other languages [without a lot of compiler hacking or similar trouble]).

Here: http://tinyurl.com/nj23hzj